# How to reduce the cold start time when using MySQL with Lambda?

Tags: java, performance, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, mysql-connector

I am trying to deploy a REST API with Java, using AWS Lambda, API Gateway and Amazon RDS (MySQL). Below is my Lambda class

```
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.aaaa.beans.AccountingType;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import static java.util.Collections.list;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

/**
 *
 * @author User
 */
public class GetAllAccountTypesLambda {


   static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://************";
   static final String USER = "*****";
   static final String PASS = "*****";
   static final String QUERY = "SELECT * from accounting_type";
   static Connection conn = null;
   
   public GetAllAccountTypesLambda()
   {
      
      try {
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
         conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   public APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent getAllAccountTypes(APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent request)
         throws JsonProcessingException, ClassNotFoundException {
      
      AccountingType acc = new AccountingType();
      ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
      List<AccountingType> list = new ArrayList<>();


      try (Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(); ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(QUERY);) {
         // Extract data from result set

         while (rs.next()) {
            // Retrieve by column name
            acc.setIdaccountingType(rs.getInt("idaccounting_Type"));
            acc.setType(rs.getString("type"));

            list.add(acc);
         }
      } catch (SQLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

      String writeValueAsString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(list);
      return new APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent().withStatusCode(200).withBody(writeValueAsString);
   }

}
```

My pom file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.aaa</groupId>
    <artifactId>aaa-restapi</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>aaa REST API</name>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <configuration></configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Now, checkout the loading time tracked from `X Ray`, which we usually call as **cold start**

[image]

It looks like the init process takes time. When further observed, I noticed most of the time is taken by the `MySQL Connector` trying to initialize. If we remove that, this will be done in 500ms to 600ms.

How can I make sure this starts much faster, probably in milliseconds? Anything to do with the MySQL connector?

Comment: One suggestion is to try connection pooling optimization?

Comment: This is AWS Lambda. Connection pool does not matter much here.

Comment: The cold start cost of the Java process itself is around 400ms already, and that's without loading any extra jars of classes. If you want to go below that, there's no way to do it in Java. Or you could minimize the amount of cold starts by e.g. pinging your lambda every 10 minutes or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't optimize blindly for cold starts. If your Lambda is going to be used in an application that is used regularly (e.g. more than 1 request per 10 seconds), the cold starts could be only 0.1% of the calls, while the other 99.9% will be processed by a warmed up lambda.

If your application is not used so much, you could still force this by e.g. sending a ping to the Lambda every 5 minutes, forcing it to keep warm.

See [Is it possible to keep an AWS Lambda function warm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42877521/is-it-possible-to-keep-an-aws-lambda-function-warm) for one way to do it. A Cloud Guru did a more extended version of it (for a javascript Lambda): https://acloudguru.com/blog/engineering/how-to-keep-your-lambda-functions-warm

The pinging does increase Amazon's overhead cost for a low-use Lambda, since they have to reserve memory for it for X hours, and they can only charge you for a couple of seconds of actual runtime for each ping. But apparently, that's a cost they are willing to take.

Comment: I agree with you. This is a rest api which will be used by millions of users. But initially, it will be just a handful. When sending ping requests, we are destroying the purpose of serverless, isnt it? Because it is supposed to charge only for what is being used, and we are sending requests just to keep it warm. Let me know your thoughts on this. On the other hand, how do you do that pinging anyway?

Comment: I added the two last paragraphs to answer your questions.

Answer (score 2):

Databases in general, and mysql in particular, are slow to establish a connection to.  To help, AWS offers a separate [RDS Proxy](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/proxy/) service that maintains a connection pool that lambdas can connect to.

However, it only supports a limited and not well documented number of database engine/version combinations, and only in certain regions.  I believe that RDS MySQL 5.6 and 5.7 are supported, as well as the corresponding Aurora versions (though not Aurora Serverless), but not 8 or any mariadb version.

Comment: I've read "use RDS proxy to reduce cold start times" many times without any follow up justification. Do you know of any actual benchmarks, or even a simple argument why this would help in the first place?

Comment: @Jake try it and see?  the argument is simply that mysql is notoriously slow to connect to.  I never implemented it myself, because of the then restrictions on which versions allowed it.